# Listing of Directory in a checkboxed tree srtucture

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create a tree-structured Directory listing having checkbox, so that we can select that directory and get that value back..

This needs to be done in c# web application.

Comment: take a look at http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer

http://forums.asp.net/p/1021570/1387710.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to have check box in front of it...??

Comment: set ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf" for the treeview